# StandardAutoload doesn't work, while ClassAutoload does

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-autoloader

I receive php fatal error "Class not found" while working on a test project (trying to learn ZF2).

```
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/classmap.php',
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Problem is simple, If I dont include my classmap, my entites dosnt load automatically, which is "okay" (as in it works now), but I would really like to know where the problem is and what is wrong...

my classmap.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
// Generated by Zend Framework 2
return array(
        'Common\Entity\Property' => __DIR__ . '/src/Common/Entity/property.php',
        'Common\Entity\Domain'   => __DIR__ . '/src/Common/Entity/domain.php',
        'Common\Module'          => __DIR__ . '/Module.php',
);
```

My error log looks like this:

```
[Sun Nov 30 17:16:40 2014] [error] [client 172.30.30.6] PHP Fatal error: 
    Class 'Common\\Entity\\Domain' not found in
     /var/www/hosts.legetimen.no/module/Frontpage/src/Frontpage/Controller/IndexController.php
     on line 38
```

(I have testet my Modeule.php with die("test"); to make sure it is loaded etc)

[EDIT]
Directory structure of my module Common:

```
$ tree Common
Common
├── classmap.php
├── config
│   └── module.config.php
├── Module.php
└── src
    └── Common
        ├── Controller
        └── Entity
            ├── domain.php
            └── property.php
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your error message you have `Class 'Common\\Entity\\Domain' not found in...` so standard autoloader is looking for `Domain.php` file not for `domain.php` so simply change to upper case first letter of filenames.

ClassMapAutoloader don't have this issue because for example `Common\Entity\Property` is mapping correctly to `/src/Common/Entity/property.php`.

Comment: Nice, that worked like a charm :) But I was under the impression that class(file)names should be lowercase?

Comment: Dont worry about it, I read the documentation :P http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html

Comment: Better look [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php#L253-L267) for how zf2 translate classname to filename in standard autoloader.